# Prompt not enough free space when I use swupdate

Tags: linux, stm32, yocto, swupdate

I encountered a problem when using the swupdate image built by yocto.

```
Software Update started !

[network_initializer] : Software update started
[extract_file_to_tmp] : Found file
[extract_file_to_tmp] : filename sw-description
[extract_file_to_tmp] : size 303
[get_common_fields] : Version 0.1.0
[get_common_fields] : Description Firmware update for XXXXX Project
[parse_hw_compatibility] : Accepted Hw Revision : 1.0
[parse_hw_compatibility] : Accepted Hw Revision : 1.2
[parse_hw_compatibility] : Accepted Hw Revision : 1.3
[_parse_images] : Found Image: rootfs.ext4.gz in device : /dev/mmcblk2p4 for handler raw
[check_hw_compatibility] : Hardware myir Revision: 1.0
[check_hw_compatibility] : Hardware compatibility verified
[extract_files] : Found file
[extract_files] : filename rootfs.ext4.gz
[extract_files] : size 373258053 required
ERROR : Not enough free space to extract rootfs.ext4.gz (needed 373258053, got 223219712)
Image invalid or corrupted. Not installing ...
[network_initializer] : Main thread sleep again !
Waiting for requests...
ERROR : Writing to IPC fails due to Broken pipe
```

As shown in the figure, it indicates that there is not enough space, and then I use `resize2fs /dev/mmcblk2p4` to expand the space. Now it has 1g of space. But still the same hint. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Hello @migu, even I am facing similar issue. Did you find a solution for this? And also how to use "resize2fs" to expand the space?

Comment: Hi,I still haven't found a solution.You can use "resize2fs  /dev/mmcblk2p4" to expand the space of /dev/mmcblk2p4.

Comment: I have made some efforts to this end.Including directly disassembling the source code and calling the check_free_space function, but I got a random value and couldn't correctly read the local block size.

Comment: Hello @migu, thanks for update. How did you call `resize2fs /dev/mmcblk2p4`? Is it part of `sw-description`? And is `/dev/mmcblk2p4` partition being updated?

Comment: This is a Linux command. You can input it directly at the terminal.It has nothing to do with swupdate.

Comment: Hi, I could solve the issue. I was copying the `.swu` file to `/tmp` folder and trying to do local update. But during update, SWUpdate will extract the file first into `/tmp` dir. Since there was no enough space left in `/tmp`, swupdate was failing. Then I copied the `.swu` file into `/etc/swupdate/` folder and tried to do local update. Now I am not getting space issue error.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the archive is first extracted to a `tmp` dir and then installed. You can do this in one step: Try using the `installed-directly` flag in the sw-description file.

```
        files: (
            {
                    filename = "rootfs.ext4.gz";
                    sha256 = "bc57b9c737033d0d6826db51618d596da7ecf3fdc0cb48dc9986a6094f529413";
                    type = "archive";
                    path = "/path/to/extract";
                    preserve-attributes = true; 
                    installed-directly = true;  <---------- this option
                    properties: {
                            create-destination = "true";
                    }
            }
```